# jquery does not work in my code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

```
<?php while(the condition here) { 
$honeyid = $row['id'];
?>
    <form action="<?=$website_url;?>/writecomment.php" name="writecomment" method="post" id="writecomment<?php echo $honeyid; ?>">
    <fieldset style="margin:3px; padding:3px; <?php if( $loggedin == "yes" ) { ?>width:410px;<?php } else { ?>width:360px;<?php } ?> background-color:#EEEEEE; border:1px solid #EEEEEE;">
    <?php if( $loggedin == "yes" ) { ?><section_write style="float:left; padding:0px 3px; margin:0px 3px;">
    <?php
                    $users2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT avatar, fullname FROM users WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");
                    $user2 = mysqli_fetch_array($users2);
                        if (strlen($user2['avatar']) == 0) {
                            $img = 'http://placeimg.com/90/90/nature';
                        } else {
                            $img = $website_url . '/assets/img/avatars/'. $user2['avatar'];
                        }
                    ?>
    <a href="<?=$website_url;?>/user/<?php echo urlencode($_SESSION['username']); ?>">
    <img src="<?= $img; ?>" width="30px" height="35px" title="<?= $user2['fullname']; ?>" border="0" />
    </a>
    </section_write><?php } ?>
    <textarea style="width:350px;height:23px" name="contectcomment" id="contectcomment<?php echo $honeyid; ?>"></textarea>
    <br />
    <?php if( $loggedin == "yes" ) { ?><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="commentanonim<?php echo $honeyid; ?>" name="commentanonim" checked="checked" style="margin:3px; padding:3px;" /><label for="commentanonim<?php echo $honeyid; ?>">Anonymously</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php } ?><input type="submit" value=" Comment "  class="comment_submit" name="dergokomentin" id="dergokomentin<?php echo $honeyid; ?>" /><input type="hidden" name="tbhidkoment" value="<?php echo $honeyid; ?>" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script>
    $("#writecomment<?php echo $honeyid; ?>").submit(function(){
        $.post( $("#writecomment<?php echo $honeyid; ?>").attr("action"), 
            $("#writecomment<?php echo $honeyid; ?> :input").serializeArray(), 
            function(info){         

    $("#contectcomment<?php echo $honeyid; ?> :input").each( function() { $(this).val(''); });
    $("#commentanonim<?php echo $honeyid; ?>").val("1");
    $("#shikokomentet<?php echo $honeyid; ?>").load("<?=$website_url;?>/loadcomments.php?id=<?php echo $honeyid; ?>");

    });
    });

    $("#writecomment<?php echo $honeyid; ?>").submit( function() {
        return false;   
    });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Ok, this is my code. I am trying to make a comment system and what I want to achieve is, when the user clicks the button "Comment", I want to clean the textarea and load the other page as it is written in the code. But it doesn't work! I have been working on this for 4 hours and still no clue. Any idea why this does not work?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by „does not work“? Can you post any error messages?

Comment: The lines of code below do not work: 

$("#contectcomment<?php echo $honeyid; ?> :input").each( function() { $(this).val(''); });
    $("#commentanonim<?php echo $honeyid; ?>").val("1");
    $("#shikokomentet<?php echo $honeyid; ?>").load("<?=$website_url;?>/loadcomments.php?id=<?php echo $honeyid; ?>");

Comment: You jQuery needs to be wrapped in $(document).ready(function() { // put your code here });

Comment: Can I do those functions with pure javascript? not with jquery?

Comment: Yes, jQuery isn’t anything else than a wrapper for pure Javascript. But to me, jQuery code is better readable and shorter.

Comment: You should write your handler just once, not repeat it for every item. Give the items a class, and then use DOM traversal functions to manipulate the elements relative to `$(this)`. This will make your jQuery code much easier to read, since it won't have all those `<?php echo $honeyid;?>` things mixed into it.